# How to get posts from two categories with WP_Query?

Tags: categories, wp-query

I'm using WP_Query to create 'latest posts' & 'popular posts' sections on my home page. I'm trying to just pull 5 posts from 2 categories (9 & 11) but it will only show posts from cat 9.

Here's the php I'm using for 'latest posts'-

```
<ul>
        <?php 

        $cat = array(9,11);
        $showposts = 5;
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args=array(
            'category__in' => $cat, 
            'showposts' => $showposts,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
           );

        $the_query = new WP_Query ( $args ); //the query


        $i = 0;while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); //start the loop
        ?>

        <?php
        if($i==0){ //Sets the output for the top post
        ?>  
            <li class="first-news">
                <div class="post-thumbnail"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(350,187); ?></a></div>
                <h2 class="post-box-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="post-meta"><span class="tie-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></span></p>
                <div class="entry"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
                <div><a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More »</a></div>

            </li>


        <?php
            $i++;
             } else { ?>

                <li class="other-news rar">
                <div class="post-thumbnail"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(145,93); ?></a></div>
                <h3 class="post-box-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p class="post-meta"><span class="tie-date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></span></p>
           </li>

        <?php } endwhile; //end of the loop ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>
        </ul>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hm, that looks like it should work. What happens if you try to query only category `11`?

Comment: Please also check not just querying 5 posts - it could be that the first five are only from category 9.

Comment: `'showposts'` is deprecated. Try using `'posts_per_page'` instead.

Comment: Oh =/ posts_per_page wasn't working for me

Comment: When things are deprecated does that mean that it'll stop working in future Wordpress updates?

Comment: @user3205234 *When things are deprecated does that mean that it'll stop working in future Wordpress updates?* - Reasonably yes. But WordPress has a vast support for older versions, so till now it's not a visible matter. But in future WordPress *can/may* stop the support and *can/may* switch them to version-specific plugins.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience using `'posts_*'` filters (`'posts_request'`, `'posts_where'`...) in combination with `str_replace` / `preg_replace` is unreliable and unflexible:

Unreliable because if another filter modify uses one of that filters, in better case one gets unexpected results, in worst cases one gets SQL errors.

Unflexible because changing an argument, e.g. 'include_children' for categories, or reuse the code for e.g. 3 terms instead of 2 need a lot of works.

Moreover, adapt code to be musltisite compatibe need to edit SQL manually.

So, sometimes, evevn if not the best solution regarding performance, a more *canonical* approach is the best and more flexible one.

And performance can be improced with some caching tricks...

My propose:

1. write a function taht make use of [`usort`](https://www.php.net/usort) to order posts coming from different queries (e.g. one per term)
2. write a function that on first run run separate queries, merge results, order them, cache them and return them. On subsequent request simply return the cached results
3. handle caching invalidation when needed

##Code##

First the function that order posts:

```
function my_date_terms_posts_sort( Array $posts, $order = 'DESC' ) {
  if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
    usort( $posts, function( WP_Post $a, WP_Post $b ) use ( $order ) {
      $at = (int) mysql2date( 'U', $a->post_date );
      $bt = (int) mysql2date( 'U', $b->post_date );
      $orders = strtoupper($order) === 'ASC' ? array( 1, -1 ) : array( -1, 1 );
      return $at === $bt ? 0 : ( $at > $bt ) ? $orders[0] : $orders[1];
    } );
  }
  return $posts;
}
```

Then the function that get non cached results:

```
function my_fresh_terms_get_posts( $args, $terms, $tax_query_args = NULL ) {
  $posts = array();
  // we need to know at least the taxonomy
  if ( ! is_array( $tax_query_args ) || ! isset( $tax_query_args['taxonomy'] ) ) return;
  // handle base tax_query
  $base_tax_query = isset( $args['tax_query'] ) ? $args['tax_query'] : array();
  // run a query for each term
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $term_tax_query = wp_parse_args( array(
      'terms' => array( $term ),
      'field' => is_numeric( $term ) ? 'term_id' : 'slug'
    ), $tax_query_args );
    $args['tax_query'] = array_merge( $base_tax_query, array($term_tax_query) );
    $q = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
      // merging retrieved posts in $posts array
      // preventing duplicates using ID as array keys
      $ids = wp_list_pluck( $q->posts, 'ID' );
      $keyed = array_combine( $ids, array_values( $q->posts ) );
      $posts += $keyed;
    }
  }
  return $posts;
}
```

Now the function that check cache and return it if available or return non cached results

```
function my_terms_get_posts( $args, $terms, $tax_query_args = NULL, $order = 'DESC' ) {
  // we need to know at least the taxonomy
  if ( ! is_array( $tax_query_args ) || ! isset( $tax_query_args['taxonomy'] ) ) return;
  $tax = $tax_query_args['taxonomy'];
  // get cached  results
  $cached = get_transient( "my_terms_get_posts_{$tax}" );
  if ( ! empty( $cached ) ) return $cached;
  // no cached  results, get 'fresh' posts
  $posts = my_fresh_terms_get_posts( $args, $terms, $tax_query_args );
  if ( ! empty($posts) ) {
    // order posts and cache them
    $posts = my_date_terms_posts_sort( $posts, $order );
    set_transient( "my_terms_get_posts_{$tax}",  $posts, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
  }
  return $posts;
}
```

**Cache is auto-cleaned daily**, however, is possible to invalidate it everytime a new post in on a specific taxonomy is added or updated. That can be done adding a cleaning cache function on `'set_object_terms'`

```
add_action( 'set_object_terms', function( $object_id, $terms, $tt_ids, $taxonomy ) {
  $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( array( 'object_type' => array('post') ), 'names' );
  if ( in_array( $taxonomy, (array) $taxonomies ) ) {
    delete_transient( "my_terms_get_posts_{$taxonomy}" );
  }
}, 10, 4 );
```

##Usage##

```
// the number of post to retrieve for each term
// total of posts retrieved will be equat to this number x the number of terms passed
// to my_terms_get_posts function
$perterm = 5;

// first define general args:
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => $perterm,
  'paged' => $paged,
);

// taxonomy args
$base_tax_args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'category'
);
$terms = array( 9, 11 ); // is also possible to use slugs

// get posts
$posts = my_terms_get_posts( $args, $terms, $base_tax_args );

// loop
if ( ! empty( $posts ) ) {
  foreach ( $posts as $_post ) {
    global $post;
    setup_postdata( $_post );
    //-------------------------> loop code goes here    
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Functions are flexible enough to use complex queries, even queries for additional taxonomies:

E.G.

```
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => $perterm,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query' => array(
     'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'another_taxonomy',
       'terms' => array( 'foo', 'bar' ),
       'field' => 'id'
     )
   )
);

$base_tax_args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'category',
  'include_children' => FALSE
);

$terms = array( 'a-category', 'another-one' );

$posts = my_terms_get_posts( $args, $terms, $base_tax_args );
```

In this way the 'tax_query' set in `$args` array will be merged dinamically with the tax query argument in `$base_tax_args`, for each of the terms in the `$terms` array.

Is also possible order posts in ascending order:

```
$posts = my_terms_get_posts( $args, $terms, $base_tax_args, 'ASC' );
```

Please note:

1. IMPORTANT: If some posts belong to more than one category among the ones passed to function (e.g. in OP case some posts have both category 9 and 11) the number of post retrieved will be not the one expected, because function will return that posts once
2. Code needs PHP 5.3+

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters):

> **Show Posts From Several Categories** (Display posts that have these categories, using category id) would be:
>
> `$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=9,11' );`

And, the Codex's Pagination Parameters says that, `'showposts'` is deprecated and replaced with `'posts_per_page'`.

> **`posts_per_page`** (*int*) - number of post to show per page (available with [Version 2.1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.1), replaced `showposts` parameter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll give that a go after I've tried the one from s_ha_dum. (posts per page wasn't really working for me before for some odd reason)

Comment: @user3205234: You should be using `posts_per_page` but it won't solve the problem I think you are having-- that one category or the other fills up your post limit before the other is represented.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a near duplicate of this question: [How do I create my own nested meta_query using posts_where / posts_join?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/114791/21376)

The problem, as @fischi suggests, is almost certainly that results are coming from one category or the other and hitting the post limit before both are equally represented. To make this work, you need a UNION. `WP_Query` is not capable of that logic, but with hooks you can make it work.

```
$cat = 9; // your first category
$showposts = 5; // actual results are twice this value
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
  'cat' => $cat, 
  'posts_per_page' => $showposts,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);

function create_cat_union($clauses) {
  remove_filter('posts_request','create_cat_union',1);
  $clauses = str_replace('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS','',$clauses,$scfr);

  $scfr = (0 < $scfr) ? 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS' : '';

  $pattern = 'wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN \(([0-9,]+)\)';
  $clause2 = preg_replace('|'.$pattern.'|','wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (11)',$clauses); // manipulate this

  return "SELECT {$scfr} u.* FROM (({$clauses}) UNION ({$clause2})) as u";
}
add_filter('posts_request','create_cat_union',1,2);

$the_query = new WP_Query ( $args ); //the query
var_dump($the_query->posts);
```

A couple of notes: `WP_Query` will parse the category argument and find category children so the first `UNION` will include all of the children of category 9. I ***did not*** duplicate that logic for category 11. If you need that functionality, you can refer to the [`WP_Query` source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/query.php#L2451) and reproduce the effect.

Comment: Oh, sorry I should have looked harder to find the answer =/

Comment: No apology necessary. The question referred to would have gotten you close, and if your PHP/MySQL are good you could have gotten to the answer, but it is not a true duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will give it a try. Not hear of UNION before, something new for me to look into. Although the newest 5 posts are definitely from both categories.

Comment: Ahh, my MySQL isn't too good yet- got a lot to learn! Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Even if the "newest five" are from both categories what you would get without the union is 3 of one and 2 of the other, or 4 of one and 1 of the other-- that is not an even return from each.