# How to get latest posts from each category in regular order

Tags: categories, wp-query, query

let's say I have a main query and it displays posts from Movies and Music categories. I want the query to show always 5 latest posts from Movies and 5 latest posts from Music category. When I create a new post in Movies category the query will show 6 posts From Movies and 4 posts from Music category. But I need a way to show always 5 latest posts from each categories on homepage.

In other words, I still want the regular query where posts are ordered by date and not categorized but want to limit the number of posts per category displayed on homepage. I found some solutions to display latest post/posts from each categories but all those solutions categorizes posts. I still want the regular wp query.

Here are two solutions: http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2010/03/10/display-5-latest-posts-in-each-category-in-wordpress/

[First post of each category](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135782/first-post-of-each-category)

As you can see posts are categorized and are not in regular order. When there is a new post it will not be at the top and will go under its own category. I really googled for hours, tried many solutions but none of them does what I want.

UPDATE: This question was marked as duplicate however I tried the mentioned answer and realized it's not what I'm looking for. I already found similar solutions but they all categorize posts. e.g.

First Movie Post - Second Movie Post - Third Movie Post

(then) First Mucis Post - Second Mucis Post - Third Mucis Post

Posts should be displayed as if it's a regular wp query where posts are displayed by date no matter which category they belong. But each category should be limited by 5 posts. So the mentioned answer is close but not exactly what I'm looking for. Sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: Could you not just run two queries, one for each category and limit the results with `posts_per_page`?

Comment: Actually I have 5 categories and will filter them using jquery. Seperate queries is not a solution for me.

Comment: @CarlisleHolm I posted an answer that solve your problem in the question that your question was marked as duplicate of. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138537/35541

Comment: G. M., Your solution is exactly what I'm looking for and works PERFECTLY! Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get posts from two categories with WP\_Query?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/132170/how-to-get-posts-from-two-categories-with-wp-query)