# Querying multiple post types ensure 1 of each type

Tags: wp-query

If I'm querying more than 1 post type, is it possible to ensure that I will always get at least 1 of each type?

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post', 'project' ),
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
);

$recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In this example, I'd like to ensure that I always have at least 1 post in the 3 posts that are returned.

I dislike how sticky posts behave as it ends up returning more than the 3 items requested and will impact other parts of my site.

Comment: `'ignore_sticky_posts' => false` returns sticky posts, which according to your question you do not want? Right

Comment: You need a `UNION` as per my answer to question marked as a duplicate. Getting a `UNION` to work with `WP_Query` is tricky, [but possible](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115236/21376).

Comment: @PieterGoosen correct. Copy/paste #fail from when I was testing out stick posts.