# Using meta_query with multiple keys and compare values

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, pre-get-posts

I suspect I may be asking for the moon on a stick with this, but:

I have a filter for my `shows` custom post type. The filter uses standard taxonomies attached to `shows`, but also allows the user to filter by Venue, which is a meta value for each show, or by Month, as there is a start date attached to each show.

The issue I've come across is that some shows may span multiple months; so, start the run in November 2014 and finish in December. For this I'm storing the meta values as follows:

```
startdate   => 20141225
enddate     => 20141224
```

Ideally, if someone filters shows for December 2014, I want to display shows that both start within December, *or* end before the end of December. The issue is that, because I'm also checking for the `venue` meta_value with `relation => 'AND'`, I can't figure out a way to check for *[pseudocode]* `WHERE venue == 'royal-playhouse' AND ((startdate BETWEEN array(20141201, 20141231)) OR (enddate BETWEEN array(20141201, 20141231)))`.

I'm using a `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the passed `$query` arguments, and it's worth noting that there are a couple more meta_value fields that are also used with the filter (such as show type, accessibility, etc.). Here's a simplified version of my code (which currently works perfectly, but only checks against `startdate`):

```
function showDates_orderQuery($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('showdates')) {

        $queryVenue = $query->query_vars['venue'];
        $queryMonth = $query->query_vars['month'];

        $metaQuery = array();

        //  Venue meta

        if ($queryVenue) {
            $metaQuery[] = array(
                'key'       => 'venue',
                'value'     => array($queryVenue),
                'compare'   => 'IN',
            );
        }

        //  Month meta

        if ($queryMonth) {

            $monthEpoch = strtotime($queryMonth);
            $formattedQueryMonth = date('Ymd', $monthEpoch);
            $formattedEndOfQueryMonth = date('Ymt', $monthEpoch);

            $metaQuery['relation'] = 'AND'; //  Set because we want to check for shows from a venue AND by the given month

            $metaQuery[] = array(
                'key'       => 'startdate',
                'value'     => array($formattedQueryMonth, $formattedEndOfQueryMonth),
                'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                'type'      => 'DATE'
            );
        }

        if ($metaQuery) {
            $query->set('meta_query', $metaQuery);
        }

        $query->set('meta_key', 'startdate');
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'showDates_orderQuery');
```

Any ideas on how I might be able to achieve this would be gratefully received.

Comment: your date format should be `yyyymmdd` to order correctly. for complex meta queries like you require, you'll have to modify the SQL directly via filters, `WP_Query` can't handle that.

Comment: @Milo Quite right - I was typing this from memory. My date formats are `yyyymmdd` in my code - updated my post to reflect this. As for the second part of your comment... *damnit*. Iwas debating if there was some other way I could write secondary meta keys that I could query or something...

Comment: As Milo mentioned it may be worth using `global $wpdb;`. You could get the wp_query as close as possible, then `print_r()` to get the sql value, then modify the `$sql` string and run it through like `$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);`

Comment: Also have you seen this post yet: [Nested meta_query with multiple relation keys](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75079/nested-meta-query-with-multiple-relation-keys)

Comment: @Xtremefaith That doesn't sound like a bad idea; I'm just dubious as to how well a method like that would play with pagination. This is all done on a standard archive page, hence using `pre_get_posts` rather than a custom query. With regards to the link: I tried nested meta queries too! At least there's confirmation it's a big fat nope, and `relation` is always a single top-level argument. Worth knowing.

Comment: the method shown in that link is definitely the way you want to go- use the `posts_join` and `posts_where` filters so you're working with the main query and not doing a custom query with `wpdb`.

Comment: @Milo Noted, and thanks to @Xtremefaith, I'm currently screwing about with the `posts_join` filter right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am a complete idiot, I seem to have completely forgotten that I [basically answered my own question over a year ago](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/119222/17826).

I was struggling to get the `posts_join` filter to behave (I generally have trouble with `INNER JOIN`s anyway), and so instead looked to the `posts_where` filter. The main issue with it is that you can't pass any arguments to it other than the existing `$where` condition; and in this instance I wanted it to use non-global variables.

The answer was to use an inline anonymous Lambda function for the `posts_where` filter:

```
if ($queryMonth) {

    $monthEpoch = strtotime($queryMonth);
    $formattedQueryMonth = date('Ymd', $monthEpoch);
    $formattedEndOfQueryMonth = date('Ymt', $monthEpoch);

    $monthOptions = array(
        'monthstart' => $formattedQueryMonth,
        'monthend' => $formattedEndOfQueryMonth,
    );

    $monthFilter = function ($where = '') use ($monthOptions) {
        global $wpdb;
        $where .= " AND (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'startdate' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= '" . $monthOptions['monthstart'] . "') AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'startdate' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= '" . $monthOptions['monthend'] . "')) ";
        $where .= " OR (($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'enddate' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value >= '" . $monthOptions['monthstart'] . "') AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'enddate' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value <= '" . $monthOptions['monthend'] . "')) ";
        return $where;
    };

    add_filter('posts_where', $monthFilter);
}
```

With any luck, this method should actually become completely redundant in the next few weeks thanks to the [forthcoming release of 4.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/20/update-on-query-improvements-in-4-1/) - thanks to @jmusal for the [heads up](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169157/17826).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your timeline or how much you want to live on the edge, there were some great improvements that are set to be introduced to 4.1 that I think will allow you to do just what you're looking to do.  If you want to live on the edge a little, you could develop with the 4.1 beta and switch to the release at the time of launch (be sure to file bug reports if you find them :) )

Here is a link to the make post that goes into a bit more detail: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/20/update-on-query-improvements-in-4-1/

Comment: I like that the very first thing mentioned is the use of nested Meta Queries! I'll have to check with the client though, as they'll have to wait until at least Dec 8th until I can put this on a production server. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can't figure out a way to do that because there is no such way. It is not possible to mix ANDs and ORs like that with meta_query. The query system is great, but not all inclusive. You will need to use multiple queries, or filter the SQL yourself.